# Create table dynamically asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-tables

I can dynamically create ordinary tables with

`Dim tRow As New TableRow() tblKategorie.Rows.Add(tRow)`
and `Dim tCell As New TableCell() tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)`

But now I need a complex table like this:[image]

How to create such this table dynamically? How can I merge cells and columns to get this result? I would be very grateful for examples or links that will help me understand this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585562/setting-rowspan-for-dynamic-rows-in-asp-net-table-control

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.rowspan(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.columnspan(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` for that.

```
'create a new table with some properties
Dim table As Table = New Table
table.CellPadding = 5
table.CellSpacing = 0
table.Width = 500
table.Height = 200

'this is just to visualize the layout
table.Attributes.Add("border", "1")

'the first row that spans all 3 columns
Dim row1 As TableRow = New TableRow
Dim cell1a As TableCell = New TableCell
cell1a.ColumnSpan = 3
row1.Cells.Add(cell1a)

'the second row where the first column spans 3 rows
Dim row2 As TableRow = New TableRow
Dim cell2a As TableCell = New TableCell
cell2a.RowSpan = 3
Dim cell2b As TableCell = New TableCell
Dim cell2c As TableCell = New TableCell
row2.Cells.Add(cell2a)
row2.Cells.Add(cell2b)
row2.Cells.Add(cell2c)

'the third row where the second column spans 2 rows
Dim row3 As TableRow = New TableRow
Dim cell3b As TableCell = New TableCell
cell3b.RowSpan = 2
Dim cell3c As TableCell = New TableCell
row3.Cells.Add(cell3b)
row3.Cells.Add(cell3c)

'the last row containing just one cell
Dim row4 As TableRow = New TableRow
Dim cell4c As TableCell = New TableCell
row4.Cells.Add(cell4c)

'add the rows to the table
table.Rows.Add(row1)
table.Rows.Add(row2)
table.Rows.Add(row3)
table.Rows.Add(row4)

'add the table to the placeholder
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot and will help in the future